# iphone how to get font character set?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know what is the font character set? or Suppose user using "Hebrew" or "chinese" keyboard means how can i identify  which keyboard he is using?

This link shows [font character set](http://www.colorpilot.com/pdfcreatorpilotmanual/IPDFDocument4/FontCharset.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't totally clear to me, but if you are asking how to determine the language of the keyboard that can be done only in iOS4.2 and above by using UITextInputMode's [`currentInputMode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputMode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UITextInputMode/currentInputMode) method (documentation linked for you).

Or do you want to get at the raw characters of some `UIFont` set?

Comment: Yes this is the one i want. Once i got the keyboard language then i will do remaining process thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the free [Fonts iPhone app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fonts/id285217489?mt=8).  Don't let the low star ratings fool you.  People give low ratings because it doesn't load fonts onto the iPhone.  It will display all the characters in different fonts in a variety of sizes.

You do need to page through to get the the hebrew or chinese characters.  That would be a nice upgrade if you could go directly to a certain range.